# How many three digit positive integers are there, the sum of whose digits is a perfect cube?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, number-theory, combinations

How many three digit positive integers are there, the sum of whose digits is a perfect cube?

I already have an answer. My answer is 24, but when I inspected the answer given, it gave 38. I do not know where I went wrong.

Here is what I did.

Case 1: sum is 1, only 1 exists 100, $1+0+0=1$

Case 2: sum is 8,

a.) 800, $8+0+0=8$

b.) by stars and bars,$ a+b+c=8,$ ${n-1 \choose k-1}$ hence ${7 \choose 2}=\frac {(7)(6)(5)!}{(2)!(5)!}=21$

Case 3: sum is 27, only 1 exists 999, $9+9+9=27.$

Therefore, adding up all the 3-digits integers I gathered from cases 1 to 3, I get $ 1+22+1=24$

Can anyone spot where I went wrong? Or do you all agree with me?

Comment: You have 2 errors - standard stars and bars will give you 10C2, but here you have to start with a non-zero digit, so it is 9C2 which is 36 for Case 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sum $8$, you must start with a "star", and after that have 7 stars and 2 bars, so ${7+2\choose 2}=36$.

Comment: That $36$ includes $800$ as a possibility, so covers the whole of Case $2$

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively for the sum $8$, you can add up the following:

- $1$ permutation of $008$
- $4$ permutations of $017$
- $4$ permutations of $026$
- $4$ permutations of $035$
- $2$ permutations of $044$
- $3$ permutations of $116$
- $6$ permutations of $125$
- $6$ permutations of $134$
- $3$ permutations of $224$
- $3$ permutations of $233$

Which comes down to $36$ permutations.